# Find the range of $\angle A$ in a triangle.

Tags: trigonometry

In a triangle $ABC$ line joining circumcenter and orthocenter is paralel to line $BC$. Find the range of $\angle A$

Solution i try:

[image]

From figure $HD =2R\cos B\cos C= OE$ and $\displaystyle \angle COE =A$

$ 2R\cos B\cos C=R\cos A$ here $R$ is circumradius of circle

$2\cos B \cos C =\cos A$ how to get range of $A$ from that point?

Comment: What do you mean by 'range'?

Comment: Range of angle $A$

Comment: You only repeated yourself. I was asking for what you meant. Do you mean, for example, the range of possible values such angles might take?

Comment: Yes Allawonder  i want the range of possible values of angle $A$

Comment: You may want to reedit the OP to that effect?

Comment: What is $R$ in your equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $C=\pi-A-B$, you have: $\cos C=-\cos(A+B)=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B$. Substituting that into your equation $-2\cos B\cos C+\cos A=0$ gives:
$$
\cos A(1+\cos^2B)-2\sin A\sin B\cos B=0,
$$
that is:
$$
\cos A(2+\cos 2B)-\sin A\sin 2B=0,
$$
or:
$$
\tan A ={2+\cos 2B\over \sin 2B}.
$$
Notice that we can choose $B$ such that $B\le C$ and thus $B\le\pi/2$.
If you now consider the function 
$$f(x)={2+\cos 2x\over \sin 2x}$$
for $x\in(0,\pi/2)$,
you can easily find its minimum to be $\sqrt3$, hence $\tan A\ge\sqrt3$ and $60°\le A\le 90°$.